# need virtual audio card in Xenserver 7.6

Tags: linux, virtualization, xenserver

is it possible to have a virtual Audio Card (VAC) in Xen server 7.6 VMs? like linux or windows VMs? 
I need to use VAC to build a solution that i need to use to inter-connect multiple VMs for audio system.